# determine whether a combination number is odd or even

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Let $k$ be a given positive integer (fixed). I want to determine whether 
$$
2n-k\choose n
$$
is even or odd, for each positive integer $n$. Is there any general result?

My attempt:

Case (1). $k=0$.

Then the power of 2 in $2n\choose n$ is $\sum _{i=1}^\infty [\frac{2n}{2^i}]-2[\frac{n}{2^i}]$. It is zero if and only if $n\geq 1$. Hence $2n\choose n$ is even if and only if $n=0$.

Case (2). $k=1$.

Then the power of 2 in $2n-1\choose n$ is $\sum _{i=1}^\infty [\frac{2n-1}{2^i}]-[\frac{n}{2^i}]-[\frac{n-1}{2^i}]$. It is zero if and only if $n=0,1,2,\cdots,2^j$. Hence $2n-1\choose n$ is even if and only if $n=0$ or $n$ is  $2^j$, $j\geq 0$.

Is my computation correct? I do not know how to solve the general case...

Comment: [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) answers this question.

Comment: Specifically, write out $2n-k$ and $n$ in binary. If there is any bit position (counting from the right) in which $2n-k$ has $0$ and $n$ has $1$, the binomial coefficient is even; otherwise, it’s odd.